# Individual image should be clicked when clicking on single image in loop map react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am repeating the images and when I am click on an individual image then that single image should be clicked not all images and need to display some info after clicking on image. Please help me with this.

```
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={this.callFunc.bind(this)}
                underlayColor="white">
                  <View>
                    {!this.state.isModalVisible && (
                      <Image source={require("./assets/characters/2.png")} style={styles.iconSize} />
               )}

                    {this.state.isModalVisible && (
                     <View>
                     <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>You Won</Text>
                       <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "#fff" }}>
                           {amt}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                  )}
                 </View> 

             </TouchableHighlight>
```

callFunc() code:

```
callFunc() { 
  if (this.isModalVisible) {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: false });
  } else {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: true });
  }
}
```

```js
let Blocks = []; 
for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.count; i++) { 
  let item = imageCharacters[i]; 
  let amt = amount[i]; 
  Blocks.push(
    <View key={i} style={styles.card}> 
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.callFunc.bind(this)} underlayColor="white"> 
        <View> {
          !this.state.isModalVisible && ( <Image source={require("./assets/characters/2.png")} style={styles.iconSize} /> )
        }
```

Comment: What is the code for callFunc?

Comment: Here is the function:callFunc() {
    if (this.isModalVisible) {
      this.setState({ isModalVisible: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isModalVisible: true });
    }
  }

Comment: callFunc() {
    if (this.isModalVisible) {
      this.setState({ isModalVisible: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isModalVisible: true });
    }
  }

Comment: let Blocks = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.count; i++) {
            let item = imageCharacters[i];
            let amt = amount[i];
            Blocks.push(<View  key={i} style={styles.card}>
             
                  <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={this.callFunc.bind(this)}
                    underlayColor="white">
                      <View>
                        {!this.state.isModalVisible && (
                          <Image source={require("./assets/characters/2.png")} style={styles.iconSize} />
                   )}

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
onPress={() => this.callFunc(i)}>


callFunc(i) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but  this code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned repeating images, that means that images are in an array, but your isModalVisible is a single property in the state... so when you toggle the isModalVisible property, it gets toggled for all the images...

What you need is to have the isModalVisible property against each image in the array.

relevant **JS**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      imgs: [
        { img: 'https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg', info: 'this was a large image', display: false },
        { img: 'https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg', info: 'this was a small image', display: false }
      ]
    };
  }

  inFunc(passedKey) {
    this.setState({ name: 'Akber' });
    var someArray = [...this.state.imgs];
    (someArray[passedKey].display == true) ? someArray[passedKey].display = false : someArray[passedKey].display = true;
    console.log(someArray);
    this.setState({ imgs: someArray });
    console.log(this.state);

    //this.setState({ this.state.imgs[passedKey].display: true  })
  }

  render() {
    var myImages = this.state.imgs.map((obj, index) => {
      if (obj.display) {
        return (
          <div className='imgDiv'> <img key={index} src={obj.img} alt='nice' onClick={this.inFunc.bind(this, index)} />
            INFORMATION:
          </div>
        )
      } else {
        return (
          <div className='imgDiv'> <img key={index} src={obj.img} alt='nice' onClick={this.inFunc.bind(this, index)} />
            INFORMATION: {obj.info} <br />
          </div>
        )
      };
    }

    )
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
        {myImages}
      </div >
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m5smvd)

Comment: Thank you Akber but this logic is completely different i do not want to  change my code, Can you please give me simple idea that i can apply on my code.